# github ssh key not saving and asking for password every time

Tags: macos, ssh, github

I have a couple repo's on my local machine from github. The last repo I just created asks me for my login/password info every time I try to communicate with the github servers. All of my other repos work just fine and don't ask me every time. I followed the instructions here:https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases but no luck. I never get the keychain popup asking for my password. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HTTPS repos usually ask for the password each time (after some 20 mins timeout I guess). Are you sure that you cloned the repo using the SSH url for the git repo - which is of the fashion: git@github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git ? With SSH keypairs, it should work for any repo - as the keys are only used for SSH protocol authentication with the github servers, and would be the same for all github repos.

Answer (score 3):

Look inside the `.git/config` file for that repo and see what the `url` section looks like. If it starts with https you will get prompted for a password. You need to use the ssh protocol for the url which would look similar to:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = git@github.com:ACCOUNT/PROJECT.git
```